# How to Insert mutliple rows from one table into another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I create an insert statement that will  insert E_PROVIDER_ID values (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, IDENTITY_ID) into E_PROVIDER_MAP where IDENTITY_ID_TYPE = 125?

I need the insertion to insert values from the ID table into the mapping table so that:

> ```
> E_PROVIDER_ID.PROV_ID = E_PROVIDER_MAP.I_PROV
> E_PROVIDER_ID.E_PROVIDER_ID = E_PROVIDER_ID.IDENTITY_ID
> E_PROVIDER_ID.E_PROV_NAME = E_PROVIDER_MAP.I_PROV_NAME
> E_PROVIDER_ID.E_PROV_NAME = E_PROVIDER_MAP.E_PROV_NAME
> ```

--Create ID Table

```
create table E_PROVIDER_ID
(
  PROV_ID          VARCHAR2(50),
  PROV_NAME        VARCHAR2(50),
  ID_LINE#         VARCHAR2(50),
  IDENTITY_TYPE_ID VARCHAR2(50),
  ID_TYPE_NAME     VARCHAR2(50),
  IDENTITY_ID      VARCHAR2(50),
)
```

--INSERT VALUES

```
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1005232', 'SMITH, BRIAN EDWARD', '5', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '020621');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1003556', 'SMITH, JOHN STUART', '4', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '026786');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1003595', 'SMITH, RICHARD F.', '5', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '029091');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1003602', 'SMITH, PAUL MATTHEW', '5', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '029761');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1003769', 'SMITH, MARC DROR', '4', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '029748');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1006776', 'SMITH, ULA V.', '6', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '034415');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1006946', 'SMITH, TIMOTHY P.', '7', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '034687');
insert into E_PROVIDER_ID (PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, ID_LINE#, IDENTITY_TYPE_ID, ID_TYPE_NAME, IDENTITY_ID,)
values ('1007032', 'SMITH, DAVID C.', '7', '125', 'PROVIDER CODE ID', '101754');
commit;
```

-- Create map table

```
create table E_PROVIDER_MAP
(
  I_PROV       NUMBER,
  I_PROV_NAME  VARCHAR2(50),
  E_PROV       NUMBER,
  E_PROV_NAME  VARCHAR2(50),
  I_REC_INST   VARCHAR2(8)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
insert into E_PROVIDER_MAP(<columns go here>)
    select PROV_ID, PROV_NAME, IDENTITY_ID
    from E_PROVIDER_ID
    where IDENTITY_ID_TYPE = 125;
```

I cannot readily tell what the list of columns should be for the "map" table.

EDIT:

Based on your comment and the edit to your question:

```
insert into E_PROVIDER_MAP(I_PROV, IDENTITY_ID, I_PROV_NAME, E_PROV_NAME)
    select PROV_ID, E_PROVIDER_ID, E_PROV_NAME, E_PROV_NAME
    from E_PROVIDER_ID
    where IDENTITY_ID_TYPE = 125;
```

I do note that these columns seem to have nothing to do with the `create table` statements in the question.

Comment: The relationship of the insertion I am trying to create is:

E_PROVIDER_ID.PROV_ID = E_PROVIDER_MAP.I_PROV

E_PROVIDER_ID.E_PROVIDER_ID = E_PROVIDER_ID.IDENTITY_ID

E_PROVIDER_ID.E_PROV_NAME = E_PROVIDER_MAP.I_PROV_NAME

E_PROVIDER_ID.E_PROV_NAME = E_PROVIDER_MAP.E_PROV_NAME

Comment: I later discovered there were characters in my dataset. The column it was attempting to insert these chars to (IDENTITY_ID) is Numeric. After removing the offending row of characters, insertion statement worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting from a table with VARCHAR columns you need to do a select insert with a cast.

insert into E_PROVIDER_MAP(I_PROV, IDENTITY_ID, I_PROV_NAME, E_PROV_NAME)
    select CAST(PROV_ID AS NUMBER), CAST(E_PROV AS NUMBER), I_PROV_NAME, E_PROV_NAME
    from E_PROVIDER_ID
    where IDENTITY_ID_TYPE = 125;